# How to type cast UIView into a CPGraphHostingView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

How to type cast UIView into a CPGraphHostingView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your UIView was not created as a real UIView object ([[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:]) try, but as a CPGraphHostingView object ([[CPGraphHostingView alloc]initWithFrame:]) try

```
(CPGraphHostingView*)view
```

as a normal type cast is written.